# Как увеличить размер кучи в Android Studio (Java Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Как увеличить размер кучи в Android Studio

[image]

Answer (score 3):

> Как увеличить размер кучи в Android Studio

К сожалению, единственный и правильный ответ - никак.

Приложение выполняется на устройстве или эмуляторе, а вовсе не в IDE. И судя по скрину у Вас перерасход памяти именно при выполнении приложения.

Что можно попробовать для решения проблемы:

- Увеличить размер кучи **для приложения** через манифест: `<application android:label="@string/app_name" android:largeHeap="true" >`;
- Перенести тяжёлые операции в нативный код;
- Оптимизировать алгоритмы работы приложения;
- Из комментария: оптимизировать ресурсы приложения (уменьшить размер картинок, заменить на `shape`, заменить растровую графику на векторную и т.д.).

Как-то так...

Comment: Судя по стеку - проблема проявляется при загрузке картинки из ресурсов. Поэтому добавлю ещё, что нужно оптимизировать ресурсы, если возможно - уменьшить разрешение картинок, заменить на шейпы, вектора и т.д.

Comment: Добавил в ответ.

Comment: а что такое (android:largeHeap="true" ) ?

Comment: А как можно из растрового изображения сделать  шейпы, вектора и т.д ??

Comment: @Yacow, это параметр, который включает увеличение размера кучи приложения. Написано же в ответе...

Comment: Растровое изображение можно попробовать сконвертировать в SVG, а оттуда уже в VectorDrawable. Но, если это не файл значка (например фоновое изображение) лучше для начала попробовать уменьшить размер или качество.

Comment: я так понял эта ошибка из за того что у пользователя нету памяти??

Comment: @Yacow, ошибка скорее всего из-за того у Вас приложение ест её слишком много.

Comment: А как можно  вызвать ситуацию ,что бы появилась такая ошибка? Потому как у меня нет такого устройства. На всех устройствах все ок а у кого то ошибка!

Comment: Можно например попробовать поиграть с размером памяти в эмуляторе...

Comment: спасибо ↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓

Answer (score 0):

Пропишите в файле манифеста в теге application атрибут `android:largeHeap="true"`